# Zend form image field - keep data when form data not valid

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to upload image with zend framework and that work. The problem is when I submit form and some other fields on form isn't valid. Then I lose parameter for image field and must to set it again.

Comment: You sould show us some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Zend Framework but is a security feauture of your webbrowser that prevents websites from populating file fields with paths to local files on your computer (imagine what evil webdevelopers could do if they populated multiple hidden fields with interesting files on your computer).

To provide some service to your visitors you could store the image in a temp location on the first submit and remove the field on the second post-attempt.